# On Linux, if I use the php command with no parameters at all, what does it expect?

Tags: linux, php

Suppose in my console window I type 'php' followed by the ENTER key. Is there anything I can enter next that has a coherent result? A filename or some php code? Nothing seems to "do" anything after that.

I suppose I'm just curious about the "barest" form the command, because it clearly doesn't do nothing (as in, it doesn't return to normal console mode awaiting input).

Comment: Try  using `php -a` instead which gives you an interactive shell where you may enter PHP commands.

Answer (score 1):

The `php` command expects you to input a valid PHP script in this **interactive mode**. Read `man php` — it says:

> If no parameter is present then the standard input is read and executed.

So in principle you can copypaste a large block of PHP code. Once you press `Ctrl-D`, the code will execute and the script will exit. (`Ctrl-D` sends an EOF to the input and signals that you're done.)

More useful is the **interactive shell** that you get when you run `php -a`:

```
$ php -a
php > echo "foo";
foo
php >
```

You can [read more](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php#108006) about the difference in the PHP documentation.